# Static Resources (js,css..) in Spring MVC app not available when adding spring-data-rest

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have an existing mvc application that works fine but when I add

```
<bean class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration"></bean>
```

to enable spring-data-rest then static resources which are served via

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

are not accessible.
Actually I get this in logs when requesting a static resource

```
2013-06-06 15:33:21,035 DEBUG DispatcherServlet.doService(823) - DispatcherServlet with name 'eips-databus' processing GET request for [/eips-databus/scripts/easyUI/themes/gray/easyui_custom.css]
2013-06-06 15:33:21,035 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(226) - Looking up handler method for path /scripts/easyUI/themes/gray/easyui_custom.css
2013-06-06 15:33:21,035 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(132) - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

Any advice?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced with same with some differences. In my case I add my handler for static resources:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static/");
}
```

After that some static files with long path (like `/a/b/c/d.css` or `/a/b/c/d.js`) served as static content but some files (like `/a/b/c.js`) is not.

I found that in my case `RepositoryRestHandlerMapping` registers itself using `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` and most of CSS and JavaScript requests handled into this handler by rules like `[/{repository}/{id}/{property}]`.

[This is a bug in Spring-Data](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAREST-56), now this fixed (thanks to Oliver Gierke), you can get fixed version 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from [snapshot repo](http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot/) and I hope this can help.